# Unable to Stream Screen using VLCJ

Tags: java, vlc, vlcj

I wanted to stream the screen using VLCJ through HTTP. I am able to do the video streaming with the webcam but when I tried stream my screen It gives me following output and the application stops:

> Java Result: -1073741676

This is the code which I am using:

```
public class StreamHttp extends VlcjTest {
static MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new NativeDiscovery().discover();     

        String options = formatHttpStream("127.0.0.1", 5555);       

        mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
        HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.playMedia("screen://", options);


        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }

    private static String formatHttpStream(String serverAddress, int serverPort) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(60);
        sb.append(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=800,scale=0,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,");
        sb.append("dst=");
        sb.append(serverAddress);
        sb.append(':');
        sb.append(serverPort);
        sb.append("}}");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Kinldy help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after some struggle and searching I found that there was an issue with VLC player 2.2.4 which is the latest release. I switched to VLC 2.1.3 and everything was perfect. Got to know that they are working to fix it. So no issue with the code.